# AngularJS app fails with a Inprog scope already in progress

Tags: angularjs

Been troubleshooting this error for many hours now. The hard part is that I am not even using $apply

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
  at angular.js:63
  at beginPhase (angular.js:14901)
  at Scope.$digest (angular.js:14343)
  at HTMLDocument.dismissClickHandler (mm-foundation-tpls.js:3282)
  at HTMLDocument.jQuery.event.dispatch (jquery.js:4435)
  at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4121)
  at Object.jQuery.event.trigger (jquery.js:4350)
  at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery.js:4901)
  at Function.jQuery.extend.each (jquery.js:374)
  at jQuery.fn.jQuery.each (jquery.js:139)
```

it happens when it calls the function with the trigger click code. It's in a directive. Here is a snippet

```
  link: function ($scope, el) {
    $scope.openBrowse = function () {
      el.find('#container').trigger('click');
    };
  }
```

Comment: Could you show the whole directive and the template please. Looks like you have some conflicting event situation where your click event is being called twice in way Anuglar doesn't like. Do you have an ng-click directive or something on #container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject $timeout to your directive and then use it

```
link: function ($scope, el) {
  $scope.openBrowse = function () {
    $timeout(function(){
      el.find('#container').trigger('click');
    });
  };
}
```

Angular will then wait for your DOM to be checked before triggering the click.

PS : angular gives you a link to get information about your error. You posted the link, but haven't read at all about the link.

Comment: WOOOHOO! :) Thanks a lot! So the problem then was that it was triggering and container id wasn't rendered yet. Thank you so much!

Comment: The `digest` or `apply` cycle in angular is an internal process. In your case, your `trigger` was made in a `apply` and  was triggering a kind of infinite loop of apply